# Sprite Kit vs Scene Kit for Building information modelling

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scenekit, bim

I am trying to develop a [building information model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Building_information_modeling) viewer for iPad and I am faced with the current challenge. Should I use **SpriteKit** or **SceneKit**? I know SceneKit is meant for rendering 3D while SpriteKit is 2D. From my research so far, SceneKit seems more appropriate for Building Information Modelling as it will represent a 3D Model of a building. However, I would like to know if I can do it with SpriteKit (I read SpriteKit is easier to learn) or should I used SceneKit? Thanks for your input. I am new to iOS dev, so any assistance would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

SceneKit and SpriteKit are very similar to each other. SceneKit is a little harder to learn but it's pretty simple. SceneKit would be the only way to have a 3D model(With the options you provided). You can have a SpriteKit scene over top of the SceneKit scene to display labels that stay put.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to use both of them. SceneKit represents 3D very nicely, but can also accept SpriteKit scenes to use for backgrounds, foreground overlays, and object textures/materials.

Answer (score 0):

You can assume SpriteKit is at Top of the SceneKit, As using SceneKit you can add 3D models into Augmented Reality while SpriteKit is used to add extra sprites onto the model.

In short SpriteKit is revolution in Gaming.